# Copy the contents of a directory into another

Tags: linux, cp

I would like to copy the contents of a directory into another. I don't want to copy the directory and all files and directories under it, but just the contents of the directory just as if it were a regular file.

Doing `cp -r target dest` copies the directory and the entire hierarchy rooted in it.

Can anyone please suggest a command to do that? I get error if I do not include the `-r` option.

(I am calling `cp` from within a C program.)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure to have understood what you want exactly, anyway something like

```
find  MyDir  -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cp "{}" destdir \;
```

will copy all files from MyDir to destdir.

Comment: `cp ./* destdir` will work too, with extra output like "omitting directory"

Comment: missed that! :D though now I remember why I do always find instead of cp!!

Comment: @Shin Thanks...I just want the contents of the directory to be copied and not any of the directory or file under it. Hope I am clear

Comment: then it is what "find ..." would do

Answer (score 1):

Use `cp * target` from inside the directory.

Check out [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) for other questions like this!

Comment: Note that this will miss any dotfiles in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
cp source/* target
```

This way it won't copy subdirectories that would need `-r`

Comment: not working. All directories and there contents are copied

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest solution would be to use `cp`:

```
cp -r source/. dest/
```

The extra **.** is the key here!